# Does WindowTester work for AWT UIs?

Tags: java, user-interface, junit, awt, window-tester

I've just come across [WindowTester](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/wintester), a JUnit GUI testing framework for "Swing, SWT and GWT".  From reading the documentation, I can't work out if it also supports AWT.  Anyone got any experience with this product?

Answer (score 0):

Swing extends from AWT, so I don't see why it wouldn't support AWT.  I reckon the best way is to try, though!

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that it will be compatible with the testing tool, does it? Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm very new to gui testing), but couldn't it be possible that the testing tool accesses data members of the Swing components (data members which do not exist in AWT components) in order to programmatically identify gui components (to have a more robust reference to the gui components in the test scripts than can be achieved by capture/playback methods). If this is the case, the tool wouldn't support AWT unless the tool is also able to recognize fields of AWT components.

Comment: @Alderat That's true... unfortunately the question isn't very clear and we have no details about what kind of GUI he's using.  This question is probably dead.